# How to solve this optimization problem using linear square?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

$x_i \in \textbf{R}^3, i = 1, 2, \cdots,N$

The problem is :

$\min \left( \sum_{i=1}^N (a_i x_i-b_i)^2 + \sum_{i=1}^{N-2} (c_i x_i+d_i x_{i+1} +e_i x_{i+2})^2 \right)$

All $a,b,c,d,e$  are constant and I want to find a set of optimal $x_i$.

How to use least square optimization approach to solve this problem?

Comment: Just differentiate each of the coefficients and set each expression to zero. This will give you two sets of simultaneous equations to solve for the coefficients. Exactly the same as least squares, just with a bit more to do.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Could you show us any of your own thoughts about the question you posted?

Comment: Hi Yujie. My plan is to create a linear system and solve a Ax=B problem using standard least square approach.

Answer (score 0):

Take partials with respect to a,b,c,d,e, equate them to zero, and solve the resulting equations.

Standard stuff.